# Installing pony via conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, ponyorm

I'm trying to install the [pony orm](https://docs.ponyorm.com/) package via conda:

```
conda install pony
```

However, the `conda install` command results in a `PackageNotFoundError`:

> PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
>
> -pony
>
> We have searched for the packages in the following channels:
>
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch

The package also doesn't show up in [Pycharm's available packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/available-packages.html).

How do I install `pony` via conda?

I'm using

- Anaconda 3
- Python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My procedure for installing packages in conda is the following:

```
conda search packagename
```

in your case:

```
conda search pony
```

in your case it returns the following:

```
pony                         0.7.1                    py27_0  conda-forge
                             0.7.1                    py35_0  conda-forge
                             0.7.1                    py36_0  conda-forge
```

It displays the pony version, python version and the anaconda channel in which the package is located.

so to install you go (-c for channel):

```
conda install -c conda-forge pony
```

If search returns no hits go to https://anaconda.org/ and type the package name into the search bar at the top. This gets you here in your case:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pony

Same information on that page as well:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pony
```

Now if there's no package on Anaconda Cloud you can still try pip which comes with conda.

So if there's no hits you just go:

```
pip install pony
```

and hope for the best :D